# User specific real time notification using sockjs and django

Tags: python, django, node.js, notifications, sockjs

I am using Django as a backend and node+redis+sockjs for real time notification.

I used this blog to set up real time notification http://ipasic.com/article/django-redis-nodejs-real-time-applications/

But Using this, message is published to all the users. How to send notification to specific user using `django` and `sockjs`?